# What is the phase difference between the source voltage and the current in an LC circuit at resonance?

Tags: ac

The phase angle is $$ θ=tan^{-1}\frac{X_{L}-X_{C}}{R} $$

But R=0 and at resonance \$X_{L}=X_{C}\$, then $$θ=tan^{-1}\frac{0}{0} $$ So, does that mean θ in this case is undetermined?

Comment: `$X_{L}=X_{C}$` should be `\$X_{L}=X_{C}\$` equals \$X_{L}=X_{C}\$. Current will be infinity BTW

Comment: Jack, the formula assumes \$R\gt0\$. But you can approach the problem using limits to reach the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\underset{R\rightarrow0}{\lim}\tan^{-1}\frac{X_{L}-X_{C}}{R}=+\frac{\pi}{2}OR-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
depending on whether the numerator is negative, positive or zero.

So a discontinuity exists whether at resonance or not when \$R=0\$.
So yes the phase angle is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

My old Radio Shack Electronics Data Book shows phase angle of zero for ideal equal inductor and capacitor in parallel. For a series circuit, phase angle is only defined with series resistance, and is also zero.

IMHO, it's rather pointless to calculate impedances and phase angles for ideal components, where formulae resolve to infinity and undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, any LC resonator has losses, which means \$R_{series}\gt 0\$

However, in an oscillator, a negative resistance can be added to compensate for resonator losses (R1 shown below). A low-Q resonator is kicked initially with 1mA and left to settle:
[image: a low-Q resonator]

In an oscillator, a sustaining source (*F_negative_resistance* below) compensates for the resonator's internal resistance (R1), so that resonator current through R1 is added back. Voltage at the top of R1 should be zero. In this simulation, LTspice's default series resistance that is auto-added to an inductor has been disabled (one milliohm?).
The net result is infinite Q...the initial 1mA kick keeps it oscillating at constant amplitude:
[image: schematic of resonator plus replenishing current source to make an oscillator]

 So net current flow through R1 only consists of reactive current traded back and forth between capacitor and inductor. One is curious to see how LTspice simulator deals with the fact that net resistance is zero. Can you determine phase of net current flowing through R1? Floating-point resolution seems to limit how close to zero net resistance approaches:
[image: net real current is limited by floating point resolution]